# java.lang.NullPointerException when referencing an array of ints from a different class

Tags: java, arrays, oop, static

I'm making a project to go through a text file and output a tally of each letter in the file.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
    public class frequencyAnalysis {

        private static String text;
        public static String alphabet;
        public static int Freq[];

    public frequencyAnalysis(String text) {
        this.text = text;
        int [] Freq = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};  //array of ints to keep track of how many of each letter there is.
        alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";  //point of reference for the program to know which number in the array should be increased
    }

    public static void freqAnalysis() throws IOException {

        String token = "";
        int index;

        File subset = new File(text);  //creates a new file from the text parameter
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(subset);

        while(inFile.hasNext()) {
            token = inFile.next();
            index = alphabet.indexOf(token);
            if (index == -1) {  //makes sure that the character is a letter
                break;  
            } else {
                Freq[index]++;
            }
        }
        inFile.close();
    }
 }
```

This is the class that's supposed to go through a given text file, and count how many of each letter there is in it.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class tester {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please type the input file path: ");  //allows the user to specify a file
        String input = in.next();

        frequencyAnalysis Freq = new frequencyAnalysis(input);

        frequencyAnalysis.freqAnalysis();  //calls the method to run through the file

        for(int i = 0; i <= 25; i++){  //prints the alphabet and the Freq array
            System.out.println(frequencyAnalysis.alphabet.charAt(i) + ": " + frequencyAnalysis.Freq[i]);  //this is where the error is
        }

    }
}
```

This is the implementation class, which allows the user to specify a file and then runs the freqAnalysis method to adjust the static Freq array, which is then printed. However, when I run the program it gives me a java.lang.NullPointerException error on the specified line. I've already figured out that the problem is in "frequencyAnalysis.Freq[i]", not in "frequencyAnalysis.alphabet.charAt(i)". However, I don't know what the problem is or how to fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

In the constuctor you create an initialize local variable int [] Freq instead of class field.
Instead of:

```
int [] freq = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
```

you should have:

```
freq = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you aren't initializing the array correctly in your `frequencyAnalysis` class.

`public static int Freq[];`

you think you're initializing it with 
`int [] Freq = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};`

but in reality it should be:
`this.Freq = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};`

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are decent, but have some flaws in coding style.

First of all, integer arrays default to initialize with zeroes, so you can simplify your initialization of `Freq`.  Also, you created a **local variable** `Freq` inside of your constructor for `frequencyAnalysis` instead of setting the **static class variable**.

You should change your constructor to this:

```
    public frequencyAnalysis(String text) {
        this.text = text;
        frequencyAnalysis.Freq = new int[26];  //array of ints to keep track of how many of each letter there is.
        alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";  //point of reference for the program to know which number in the array should be increased
    }
```

Also, class names should always be capitalized! (Change it to `FrequencyAnalysis`)

Comment: I've always capitalized single word variables, but for multiple word variables I don't capitalize the first word, but then capitalize the rest (like "userInput" or "thisVariable".)

Comment: I wasn't talking about variables, I'm saying that class names should be capitalized and in CamelCase.  According to the [Documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#15411): "Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalized. Try to keep your class names simple and descriptive..."

Answer (score 0):

To let you know that is happening,

public frequencyAnalysis(String text) {
        this.text = text;
        int [] Freq = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};  //array of ints to keep track of how many of each letter there is.
        alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";  //point of reference for the program to know which number in the array should be increased
    }

When you do this int [] Freq is a new local variable the scope is limited to constructor and at the other side public static int Freq[]; is still Null, point to same variable for initialization, as stated above by others